# How do we create a minrex when the issue involves a database query?

Tags: python, sqlite, treeview, tkinter-canvas

What is the proper way to create a minimum reproducible code example when the issue only shows up when querying an SQLite database from within a Python script but the same query works directly?

When I've tried to post the Python code I am running my questions get down checked because you can't reproduce the error without the database. I can't provide the entire database as parts of it are proprietary. I can provide a subset of the database but I don't know how to do that.  If I replace the database query with a loop creating a bunch of large labels then the scrolling works properly. The query is working correctly as I can print out all the items as I read the cursor. I can  show a screen shot that shows the failure of the y scroll to show but again, those questions get down checked.

It's related to trying to use Python and tkinter with a canvas to create a 2 way scrollable frame that is populated by a treeview created with a query.

Comment: This really belongs on the meta site, because it's about how to use SO.  There are similar questions there already for example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333796/how-do-i-ask-mysql-questions-without-exposing-my-database and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query.

Comment: If the GUI works with dummy data but not query data I would be inclined to check that the dummy and query data are _exactly_ the same types and values.  It sounds as if the problem might be in the code between the db and the GUI.  But I don't know much about tkinter, so I could be wrong.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you want to do the right thing (providing a minrex)!
Since the same query "works directly", it might be a subtle difference in the expected contents (nil, empty list, ...). I would instrument the Python code to dump the result of the query (instead of passing it to tkinter), so that you can compare what you are *really* getting from Python. Said in another way: the general idea is to remove as much code as possible while the error is still present.

Comment: I have and I can print out the correct contents in the console as python reads the cursor. The issue turned out to not be the query at all (as I suspected) but with how tk Treeview handles the display of database results. So you have to have a database to see the issue which is not being able to get scrolling to work on a treeview in a frame in a canvas to have both ways of scrolling. with a proper scrollbar.

Comment: See the [tag:sql] wiki